# Best way to control who can create sites and subsites in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: permissions

I would like to control who can create sites and subsites within SharePoint 2010.

"New Site" appears on the site actions menu and users can create sub sites within Site Actions - Site Settings - Sites and Workspaces.

I was suspecting there was a permission that would remove those options from the user.  Ideas?

thx

Answer (score 1):

If a user has Contribute permission, by default it will not have privileges to create subsites. You can further customize Permission Level for each group via Permission Levels page. Learn more about [Managing Permission Levels](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/manage-permission-levels-HA010117209.aspx).

E.g. to customize default Contribute level go to:
http://your_site/_layouts/editrole.aspx?role=Contribute

Answer (score 0):

Make your users a member of the default **Members** group. This group only has **Contribute** access by default, which will not allow them to create new sites.